# Navbar which is used react app made by using bootstrap is not full width

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have made a Navbar which is made using Bootstrap, it's not full width, Here is the image
[image]

I have tried adding **nav-fill w-100** class but it didn't worked, Here is my Navbar.js code

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Navbar(props) {
    return (
        <nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode} `}>
            <div className="container-fluid  ">
                <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">{props.title}</Link>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">{props.aboutText}</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className={`form-check form-switch text-${props.mode==='light'?'dark':'light'}`}>
                        <input className="form-check-input" onClick={props.toggleMode} type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault"/>
                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Enable DarkMode</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

Navbar.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    aboutText: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

Navbar.defaultProps = {
    title: 'Set title here',
    aboutText: 'About'
  };
```

Comment: What about the nav bar's parent element? Does it have the full viewport width?

Comment: I did not get, what u said, shall I show you my app.js file?

Comment: I recommend you to use the browser's dev tools to investigate the width of the elements. If your nav bar has 100% width, this means that it has the full width of the parent element. But if the parent element doesn't have the full width of the website (viewport), you would still have a smaller nav bar.

Comment: Ok, I will check that first

Answer (score 0):

You can use vw instead of %. When you're using width it will take 100% of the parents width. However when you want to use the width of the view you can just

```
.navbar{
  width: 100vw!important;
}
```

Comment: It did not work, in fact, it increased the width from the right side, I think the issue is that the navbar is starting from a little right, it not moving towards the left now, so the issue is there on the navbar starting point